# Method removed from DLL but client not getting error

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I have a query regarding dotnet framework.
Suppose I have a class library DLL for my clients, which have set of methods. For some reason, I have removed some methods, and deliver it to my client. How I could ensure that my client will not get any error in their code because of removed of methods as they are using it.

Comment: I'd say you should never remove methods or properties from a public API that is being used by a customer. I would instead say you should mark obsolete methods etc. as `obsolete` and give a meaningful message so that the user knows what the correct call should be. I'd always advocate backwards operability with as little customer interaction as possible.

Comment: Magic? I don't know :)

Comment: I go with @StephenRoss´s answer but would like to add that obsolete methods should be deleted after a given time or releases. Otherwise your API ends up like the Android SDKs which have more obsolete methods like normal ones. And your clients curse you for not knowing how to use your API :)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think **obsolete** would be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the methods they will certainly get an error so marking them as obsolete would be the best solution to go. You will break compatibility between the code using different versions of your DLL which is quite bad and unpleasant for clients.